# Gradle execution fails when apply Unit Test in Test Artifact

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use JUnit in Android Studio but I´m having the following issue when I change the Test Artifcat from **Instrumentation tests ** to **Unit Tests**

```
:app:mockableAndroidJar FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
    > class org.objectweb.asm.tree.ClassNode has interface org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor as super class
```

Also gives this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mockableAndroidJar'.
> org/objectweb/asm/tree/ClassNode
```

Do someone know why is this happening?

The error not appears when I use the other Test Artifact.